# How to get Visual Studio use a .clang-tidy configuration file when invoking clang-tidy?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clang-tidy

Visual Studio (Desktop) has a clang-tidy integration. you can make VS invoke clang-tidy with a list of checks.
however, I could not find a way to make it use an existing .clang-tidy configuration file.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/clang-tidy?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) hints that it is possible:

> Clang-Tidy configuration By default, Clang-Tidy does not set any
> checks when enabled. To see the list of checks in the command-line
> version, run clang-tidy -list-checks in a developer command prompt.
> You can configure the checks that Clang-Tidy runs inside Visual
> Studio. In the project Property Pages dialog, open the Configuration
> Properties > Code Analysis > Clang-Tidy page. Enter checks to run in
> the Clang-Tidy Checks property. A good default set is
> clang-analyzer-*. This property value is provided to the --checks
> argument of the tool. Any further configuration can be included in
> custom .clang-tidy files. For more information, see the Clang-Tidy
> documentation on LLVM.org.

This is what I tried to do manually via the VS property pages:

[image]

But when running analyses on a file, it doesn't work.

So How to get Visual Studio use a `.clang-tidy` configuration file when invoking clang-tidy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property pages are for setting clang-tidy checks directly (not a path to the .clang-tidy file). Visual Studio should automatically detect the .clang-tidy file in your workspace, as long as it's in the same or a parent folder of your source files.

Comment: "as long as it's in the same or parent folder of your source files" is exactly the problem when building out of source (CMake).

Comment: You can manually trigger Visual Studio clang-tidy with `Analyze > Run Code Analysis`. In my case clang-tidy checks was not appearing because one of the checks caused an access violation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Visual Studio may invoke clang-tidy from a directory outside the source tree in cases where the build is generated out-of-source (as commonly happens when using CMake).

I found a small hack around it. Basically I trick Visual Studio into thinking I am giving it a list of checks, where in fact I give it the path to the config file along with whatever arguments I want. (note the extra `"` characters).

[image]

This is of course a hack. But still might serve somebody.

Here is a way to do that with CMake:

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES
    VS_GLOBAL_RunCodeAnalysis false

    # Use visual studio core guidelines
    VS_GLOBAL_EnableMicrosoftCodeAnalysis false
    #VS_GLOBAL_CodeAnalysisRuleSet ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.ruleset
    #VS_GLOBAL_CodeAnalysisRuleSet ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.ruleset

    # Use clangtidy
    VS_GLOBAL_EnableClangTidyCodeAnalysis true
    VS_GLOBAL_ClangTidyChecks "-* \"\"--config-file=${MY_CLANG_TIDY_CONFIG_PATH} --header-filter=.*" 
)
```

Comment: has this hack worked for anyone? I defined the simples config file containing just `Checks: '*'` but it doesn't work for me